# what difference between KubernetesClient and OpenshiftClient in fabric8

Tags: fabric8

I am learning fabric8,

When I use KubernetesClient, it can access pods and return res

```
    KubernetesClient k8sClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient();

    try {
      PodList podList = k8sClient.pods().inNamespace("myns").list();
      logger.info("There are {} }pods in myns namespace.", podList.getItems().size());
    } catch (KubernetesClientException exception) {
      logger.info("error: {}", exception.getMessage());
    }
```

When I use openshiftClient, it failed to return any results and no any errors.

```
    OpenShiftClient openshiftClient = new DefaultOpenShiftClient();


    try {
      PodList podList = openshiftClient.pods().inNamespace("myns").list();
      logger.info("There are {} }pods in myns namespace.", podList.getItems().size());
    } catch (KubernetesClientException exception) {
      logger.info("error: {}", exception.getMessage());
    }
```

I am curious what difference between KubernetesClient and OpenshiftClient. In fact my cluster is a OpenShift 4.7.32, my fabbric8 version is

```
    implementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-client', version: '5.8.0'
    implementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-api', version: '3.0.12'
```

Any ideas for that?

Comment: As the name suggests, OpenShiftClient is specific to Red Hat OpenShift container platform. It's a superset of KubernetesClient which is only applicable to vanilla Kubernetes clusters. With OpenShiftClient you get access to various Red hat OpenShift specific resources like DeploymentConfig, Routes etc.

Comment: Regarding your error, Could you please provide some details so that we can reproduce? I think result should be same for both clients (OpenShiftClient just extends KubernetesClient interface)

Answer (score 0):

[KubernetesClient](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.fabric8/kubernetes-client/5.9.0/jar) is the base of all clients provided by Fabric8. It is most popular module among all provided modules and is used when user only needs to access Kubernetes native resources (For example, `Deployment`, `Pod`, `Service` etc) or Custom Resources (via [Fabric8 KubernetesClient CustomResource API](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#resource-typed-api)). For most cases, you'd only need to manage basic Kubernetes Resources and would only need `KubernetesClient`, which is available via this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[OpenShiftClient](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.fabric8/openshift-client/5.9.0/jar) is specific to [Red Hat OpenShift](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/cloud-computing/openshift) container platform. It is a superset of `KubernetesClient` which means you get all the functionality of KubernetesClient along with some additional support of OpenShift specific API groups. Some examples of these are:

- [DeploymentConfig](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/applications/deployments/what-deployments-are.html#deployments-and-deploymentconfigs_what-deployments-are) `openshiftClient.deploymentConfigs()`
- [Route](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/rest_api/network_apis/route-route-openshift-io-v1.html) `openshiftClient.routes()`
- [BuildConfig](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/rest_api/workloads_apis/buildconfig-build-openshift-io-v1.html) `openshiftClient.buildConfigs()`
- [ImageStream](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/rest_api/image_apis/imagestream-image-openshift-io-v1.html) `openshiftClient.imageStreams()`
- [Project](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/rest_api/project_apis/project-project-openshift-io-v1.html) `openshiftClient.projects()`
- [Template](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/rest_api/template_apis/template-template-openshift-io-v1.html) `openshiftClient.templates()`

If you would not have been using OpenShiftClient, you would be accessing these resources via [Fabric8 KubernetesClient Generic API](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#resource-api). with OpenShiftClient, you get model classes and DSL support for these OpenShift specific resources. You can have a look at [OpenShiftClient interface](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/openshift-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/openshift/client/OpenShiftClient.java) to see all the additional DSL endpoints provided. You can access this via the `openshift-client` module:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>openshift-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried reproducing your issue by trying out your code on [Red Hat OpenShift Developer Sandbox](https://developers.redhat.com/developer-sandbox) by running these code samples on OpenShiftCluster:

KubernetesClient:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (KubernetesClient k8sClient = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
      PodList podList = k8sClient.pods().inNamespace("rokumar-dev").list();
      logger.info("There are {} pods in myns namespace.", podList.getItems().size());
    } catch (KubernetesClientException exception) {
      logger.info("error: {}", exception.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

OpenShiftClient:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (OpenShiftClient k8sClient = new DefaultOpenShiftClient()) {
      PodList podList = k8sClient.pods().inNamespace("rokumar-dev").list();
      logger.info("There are {} pods in myns namespace.", podList.getItems().size());
    } catch (KubernetesClientException exception) {
      logger.info("error: {}", exception.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

However, it gives same result for me in both cases. I see you're using [kubernetes-api](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.fabric8/kubernetes-api/3.0.12/bundle)(which is using quite old version of Fabric8 OpenShift Client(see code [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/blob/v3.0.12/pom.xml#L140))). This module is marked deprecated and is no longer maintained. I think if you run this code with `openshift-client` dependency it should work